# Android (specifically Nexus 7 2012) adb unauthorized no RSA popup

Tags: android, debugging, adb, rsa, adt

I had a fully working USB debugging between my Windows 10 PC and my Nexus 7. However after a cleanup of my drives I somehow managed to mess it up.
(Presumably I deleted the .android folder containing the RSA keys)
I should still be able to reset the keys and get the RSA popup just like in the case of a new computer. However I get no popup and I have tried nearly everything.

The PC:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- adb version 1.0.32 (latest)
- Latest Google usb drivers

The tablet:

- Nexus 7 2012 wifi edition (grouper)
- Stock 5.1.1 (Lollipop)

Things I've tried:

- Delete RSA keys in Users/username/.android
- Update USB drivers (they were up to date)
- Update ADB
- Revoking USB authorization
- Switching USB debugging on and off multiple times
- Checking MTP/PTP/none in the USB storage options

Ever since no RSA popup has appeared and `adb devices -l` is obviously listing the tablet as "unauthorized"

Is there a possible fix to this behaviour or is Windows just confused and needs a reset? Is it likely that an OS reinstall would solve the issue?

EDIT: Ended up reinstalling Windows and it is working properly. Probably somewhere drivers may have got messed up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple `.android` locations in your system - make sure to delete the right one (or all of them)

from http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html :

> if `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` is set, `adb` will use `%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\.android\`
>   instead