# Android adb device unauthorized

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I was debugging Android Studio projects on my Nexus 5 for several months without any problems. I then installed `Kali Nethunter` and now there's no way I can debug my program. I tried reinstalling the drivers, unplugging-plugging, `adb kill-server` and `start server`. USB debugging is allowed, but I can't get the check authorization window. 
`adb devices` says that my device is unauthorized

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37632540/1778421

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, yeah its Kali issues..

Supposed workaround is here:

https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/issues/341

Last message is probably the bet workaround to try first..if you do not have a 2nd real device use an emulator and follow the same directions

Comment: Reinstalled android (without Kali), the same problem. Seems there is an issue with adb keys on the computer (from the previous android systems)

Comment: Let's see, not sure what the solution is as I wanted to prevent from doing full reinstall of the android sdk to fix it...I had to do that once sometime ago its not fun..

Comment: Reinstalling windows, android and android studio worked. Thanks for helping me finding the issue! Probably there is a way to fix it without reinstalling all, but I couldn't find it